# Colours (colors) looks wrong on my Nokia Windows Phone

Tags: css, colors

This website: http://pamplonaenglishteacher.com

Source code here: https://github.com/Yorkshireman/pamplona_english_teacher2

The background is a subtle gradient.

I am using an autoprefixer, so no problem with vendor prefixes.

Background colour looks fine on my laptop, several friend's mobiles, mac, and ipad.

However, on my Nokia windows phone (internet explorer), the background is a bright garish red, and I don't think there is any gradient.

Why?

And how do I fix it?

It's got me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using color values for your start and end gradient that are very similar shades of red. Even minor monitor/device/browser setting differences are going to possibly interpret those differently enough to be a wash. When I load it in Chrome on a macbook, it's a wash of red, but I can see the gradient barely on my iPad but changing the second values saturation or lightness has the gradient showing up.

I don't see a CSS properties or naming issue that I know of, just color choices, if that helps.